# Remove LineNumberTable and filter LocalVariableTable?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Some frameworks read method argument names using debug information from the bytecode. But debug information contains much more.

In order to minimize class size (just wondering), we might remove all `LineNumberTable` data and filter `LocalVariableTable` by removing everything except method argument names. Or just to filter variables, leaving line numbers, so stracktraces remain with the line numbers.

Does anyone knows if this would work (before I test it out:)? Or a tool that may do this (before I write my own:)?

Thanx.

**EDIT** To clarify my question: would a library (jar) modified in explained way (e.g. stripped some LocalVariableTable data) would work in java eco-system (from android to app servers - jboss, websphere...)?

**EDIT #2** I have created a quick-and dirty tool for striping, and here are some results.

```
original jar size: 1,288,625
stripped just non-method local variables: 1,272,095  (99%)
removed and LineNumberTable: 1,192,492 (93%)
```

From these results (if my code is correct;) we can conclude that filtering LocalVariableTable does not help in minimizing; what only make sense is stripping LineNumberTable - but we gonna loose numbers in stack traces.

Now just to figure if jar can work with just LineNumberTable removed.

Comment: Ive made this tool here: https://github.com/oblac/tools/tree/master/src/jodd/tools/minn

Answer (score 1):

Just compile with the `-g:none` option to remove this data.

To decrease classsize further, you can compile without StackMaps using `-target 1.5`. Unfortunately, the Java 7 compiler requires you to also compile with `-source 1.5` if you do this, for no apparent reason.

Of course, this will remove all debug information. If you want to preserve certain pieces of information for use with a framework, the details will depend on the framework in question.

Comment: I know about g:none, and I do not want to remove all data. I am asking about partial debug data removal, as explained; something i never stumbled on before.

Comment: Well if you want it to work with a specific framework, you'd have to specify the framework so that I could see what information it is looking at.

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear enough, see my edit. I wonder if such library, modified in explained way, would work in java world as before. I wonder if there might be problem with loading classes with partial LocalVariableTable.